# How to disable a component from enlarging JPanel in GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

So in my code I create a window which presents you with two options, each option is a JLabel on top of a JButton.  However, when the text in one of the JLabels is too long, it pushes the other "side" out of the frame, so you have to stretch the width of the frame to even be able to see the other button.

Here's how it looks:

How it's supposed to look:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgz0B.png]

How it looks when the text is too long

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQMS0.png]

How do I make it so that the JLabel doesn't push the other side out of the frame  I tried to use setMaximumSize() but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's the snippet of code that governs this:

```
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JPanel options = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    JLabel artistOne = new JLabel(one.getArtist());
    JLabel artistTwo = new JLabel(two.getArtist());
    JButton albumOne = new JButton(one.getName());
    JButton albumTwo = new JButton(two.getName());

    albumOne.addActionListener(this);
    albumTwo.addActionListener(this);

    artistOne.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    artistTwo.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    albumOne.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    albumTwo.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    c.insets = new Insets(0, 25, 0, 25);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    options.add(artistOne, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    options.add(albumOne, c);

    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    options.add(artistTwo, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    options.add(albumTwo, c);

    pane.add(options);
```

Comment: What is the point of having a long label if you can't see all the text? What is the point of setting an arbitrary maximum size? Just limit the number of characters in the label.

Comment: From the uncompilable code snippet, I'm guessing the label would better be a (possibly uneditable) `JTextField`. That way, the size could be set in the number of columns, and the user could scroll the text left / right to see the entire String it contains. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give your suggestions a shot!